# Subscribe to wallet address

Tags: web3js, transactions

I'm stuck on how to subscribe to events to non-contract addresses. Is this possible? All I'm seeing is subscription to eth contracts only.

Comment: What exactly would you like to listen? There's no event emitted from an EOA (or as you said, non-contract address). Are you more looking for getting all the transactions related to one account? Or getting all the events related to one specific account from a particular smart contract?

Comment: @ChenchenYo I essentially want to listen to all transactions that are received by a certain EOA in the end. I want to create an alert any time money has hit that address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `web3.eth.subscribe`, where the documentation is [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#).

```
function subscribeToTxs(address) {
return web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (err, txHash) => {
    if (err) {
        throw(err);
    }
})
.on("data", function(txHash){
    return web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash, (err, returnedValue) => {
        if (err) {
            // error handling
        }
        if (returnedValue && (returnedValue.from === address || returnedValue.to === address)) {
            console.log(`TransactionHash: ${returnedValue.hash}`);
        }
    })
});
```

}

Please pay attention that here the returned hash for pending transactions, but not mined transactions. You could do further status check or subscribe to `'newBlockHeaders'` [(see docs)](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders) for mined transactions.

Comment: Getting the returnedValue as null.

Comment: Yep. It's related to the error handling part. If an error returned with `getTransaction`, then there's no returnedValue. I edit the code and you could try again.

Comment: This ignores internal transactions. If a smart contract sends eth to the EOA address from inside a method call, for example, that would not be captured. The `to` address, in that case, is the smart contract. The `from` is the caller of the smart contract.

Comment: What @ThomasJayRush mentioned is correct. Unfortunately, there's no out of the box solution in web3js library to deal with internal transactions. One possible way to extract internal transactions is through ethereum clients, such as [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction) and [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/JSONRPC-trace-module.md#trace_replaytransaction)

Comment: TrueBlocks (my project) is building an out of the box solution to this exact problem. We have a long way to go, but making great progress.

Comment: @ChenchenYo Why are so many errors returned and how can I combat that? Accepting this as the answer but would like to know the reason behind the errors.